# How we can set scrollbar on last row of data grid in WPF

Tags: wpf

[image]

How we can set  scrollbar on the last row of data grid in WPF

```
                        <ScrollViewer>
                            <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding   CM.SupportMessagesList}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Transparent" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"  IsReadOnly="True" Background="White" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" RowHeaderWidth="0" ColumnHeaderHeight="0"  x:Name="SupportMessagesGrid"  >
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
```

Scrollbar by default is shown on the last row of the data grid and the last row is displayed.

Comment: Is this an issue or requirement?

Comment: You need to put scrollbar inside column control. Add a property to show/hide conditionally by binding its value from the backend.

Answer (score 2):

```
                 <!-- SizeChanged event is create in DataGrid -->

                   <ScrollViewer  x:Name="MessageScrollbar" CanContentScroll="False">

                      <DataGrid SizeChanged="SupportMessagesGrid_SizeChanged"></DataGrid>

                    </ScrollViewer>

                    <!--Code-->

                   private void SupportMessagesGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)

                   {

                         MessageScrollbar.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewSize.Height + 50); 

                        //We got actual height of DataGrid  using  e.NewSize.Height

                   }
```